# C++ Equivalent to a Scanner's .nextFloat() method?

Tags: java, c++

I'm starting to write C++ and I'm trying to read a text file that is formatted like this:

```
32.0      12.43
503.2     3.212
```

etc.

In Java, I could use a `Scanner` with `.nextFloat()`, and put the contains into an `Array`. I am trying to achieve the same thing with C++. How is this done?

Comment: welcome to C++, be ready to get screwed anytime xD (don't mind)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse why'd say that? he is asking for some equivalent in C++. did you mean to ask his so far research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read from standard input

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   float f1, f2, f3, f4;
   std::cin >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4;       
}
```

To read from a file

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream fin("file.txt"); //fin is an arbitrary identifier
   float f1, f2, f3, f4;
   fin >> f1;
   fin >> f2;
   fin >> f3;
   fin >> f4;  // or fin >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4; no difference     
}
```

To read all floats into an array (vector) of floats, you can use this:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> //for istream_iterator and back_inserter
#include <algorithm> //for copy

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
    std::vector<float> v; //could also initialize with the two-iterator constructor
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(fin), 
              std::istream_iterator<float>(), 
              std::back_inserter(v)); //push_back into vector
}
```

Read more about stream input/output [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) and elsewhere.
I would also strongly advise that you read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Armen, is this reading from a console or a file? I'm trying to read from a file.

Comment: @Derek: Updated with an example with array

Comment: The first part really really needs an error check, or you don't know whether it's safe to read the variables afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

C++ has many good native options to read data, e.g., std::cin for user input data and std::ifstream for files.
But if you are looking for a quite similar implementation of Java Scanner you can find it in the open source project called Scanner++: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scannerpp/

Many good features of Java Scanner class are implemented there, including the nextFloat() method.

```
#include "Scanner.h"

using namespace scannerpp;

int main()
{
    // to work with strings
    Scanner scanner("32.0   12.43 \n 503.2   3.212");
    float x = scanner.nextFloat();

    // to work with files
    Scanner scanner(new File("test-data.txt"));
    float x2 = scanner.nextFloat();
}
```

Hope this helps!

DISCLAIMER: I'm co-author of Scanner++ project.

Comment: Scanner++ project has currently moved to GitHub: https://github.com/optframe/scannerpp

Answer (score -2):

You can build a String Tokenizer using string::find() or use strtok() or use Boost Tokenizer. I don't know of a pre-existing Scanner equivalent.

Also look at this thread: [Converting from Java to C++ Reading a File, and parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348686/converting-from-java-to-c-reading-a-file-and-parsing)

Comment: It's letting him know that there aren't many robust Scanner equivalents. And giving him a few options to write one himself. How does it not?

Comment: I did. It's a good answer but I don't think it's a Scanner equivalent. What if he has a more complex file format or a larger number of floats?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you should've answered the answer pertaining to Q, rather than thinking about what if xyz happens next.

Comment: That's okay. I still think this is a valid answer. If someone wants a Scanner equivalent then they would probably want to use it in other problems then the one case stated. We don't have to agree.

Comment: Note that for more complex formats, [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/) would be my recommendation.